# git squash all commits till specified date into one Commit

Tags: git, version-control

I need to squash all commits, want all commit till a specific date to be in a single commit, how can we do that?

So that if I've below commits:

| commit_id | Commit msg | commit date |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
| abcd | My Commit 4 | 2023-05-01 |
| efgh | My Commit 3 | 2023-04-01 |
| ijkl | My Commit 2 | 2023-02-01 |
| mnop | My Commit 1 | 2023-03-01 |

my expectation is below if i specify date `2023-04-01`

| commit_id | Commit msg | commit date |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
| abcd | My Commit 4 | 2023-05-01 |
| xyz | My Squashed Commit | 2023-04-01 |

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows or *nix? You might need scripting to achieve this. To my knowledge, there are no built-in commands for this.

Comment: I'm using Linux @Kitswas